# Size of the input / output parameters in the pipeline step in Azure

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

while running pipeline creation python script facing the following error.
"AzureMLCompute job failed. JobConfigurationMaxSizeExceeded: The specified job configuration exceeds the max allowed size of 32768 characters. Please reduce the size of the job's command line arguments and environment settings"

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we tried to pass a quite lengthy content as argument value to a Pipeline. You can try to upload file to blob, optionally create a dataset, then pass on dataset name or file path to AML pipeline as parameter. The pipeline step will read content of the file from the blob.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen that error before! My guess is that you're passing data as a string argument to a downstream pipeline step when you should be using [PipelineData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipelinedata?view=azure-ml-py) or [OutputFileDatasetConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.outputfiledatasetconfig?view=azure-ml-py).

I strongly suggest you read more about [moving data between steps of an AML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-move-data-in-out-of-pipelines)

Comment: I'm getting this issue on pipeline runs submitted through the designer with a pipeline that has been run many dozens of times successfully till today.   I have even tried re-submitting previously successful runs of this pipeline (i.e. exact same data inputs and pipeline as a success) which still failed with this error.  Nothing has changed on my side.  Any ideas?